# Phase diagram and interval definition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to know what is the phase line for the next autonomous differential equation:

$$x'=x\sin(\arctan(x))$$

Let's call $f(x)=x\sin(\arctan(x))$. The only root of $f$ is $x=0$. In addition, if you plot it, you can see $f$ it's not continous at $x=0$. How can I know its phase diagram?

In other exercises similar to this one, $f$ usually has at least two roots so I can bound the solutions betweens those two points, but I do not kow how to do it with only one root.

In addition, I woulk like to know the domain of the maximal solutions. I think they have to be $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$ (due to the discontinuity in $x=0$).

Comment: I meant phase line, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at a [*Wolfram Alpha plot*](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x+sin%28acrtan%28x%29%29), we see that the slope is always positive, but from the left, it is decreasing to zero, and on the right, it is increasing to infinity.

We can draw the function and then superimpose the phase line to show this as

[image]

The final result is that at $x^* = 0$, you have what type of stability?

We can also plot the direction field, to show the same result, as

[image]

**Update** If you want to do more analysis of this ODE, you can also find an implicit solution because it is a Separable Equation as

$$\sinh^{-1}(x(t)) -\dfrac{\sqrt{x(t)^2 + 1}}{x(t)} = t + c$$

You can also look at numerical solutions.

Comment: I have done this too, but I want a ""mathematical justification"". I mean, a kind of analytic proof.

Comment: And what about the domain of the solutions? For instance, let's take $x_0\in(0,+\infty)$, what would be the domain of the maximal solution in that case?

Comment: The solution is valid over that entire range.

Answer (score 0):

For $y\in(-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2)$ we have $\cos y>0$ and thus
$$
\sin(y)=\frac{\tan y}{\frac1{\cos y}}=\frac{\tan y}{\sqrt{1+\tan^2y}}
$$
This means that your ODE can be transformed to
$$
x' = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{1+x^2}}
$$
which now is a usual separable ODE, even sub-linear for global existence, with a semi-stable equilibrium point at $x=0$.